# Filtering datatable with dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to have a data table populated by a mysql database "filter" down to the option selected in the drop down box. no submit button.

basically think of it like a list of songs and for the heading of band names there would be a drop down and if you select a band it would only show songs from that band.

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT Band FROM Music"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 



$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$row["Band"]\">".$row["Band"]; 
} 

echo '<table border="1"; spacing="0"; padding="10px">
<tr>

<th><SELECT NAME=Band> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Band 
'.$options.'
</SELECT></th>
<th>Album</th>
<th>Song</th>
</tr>';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM music");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Band'] . "</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Album'] . "</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Song'] . "</center></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table><br><br><br>";
```

Comment: What you have tried and paste some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do this.  PHP is a server-side language and can't perform a client-side task.  You could make the artist selection a form item, submit the artist name/ID to the DB and then return the songs for the chosen artist, but it wouldn't work the same way you'd like it to.

Comment: That is what I was thinking but was hoping to get around this. Maybe with AJAX I could solve this?

Comment: Since anything you pass to a DB via JS is going to be accessible by everyone viewing your site, I would suggest designing an alternate method to this issue.  I think your options are either a multiple step filter (select artist > submit > get results) or front-load ALL your artists and their results and then call them based on the JS selection (a crap-ton of overhead).